# Mongoose $elemMatch with multiple of the same property

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to `find()` with Mongoose with the following query:

```
let users = await models.users.find({
  inv: { $elemMatch: { name: "Some Item", name: "Another Item" } }
});
```

These documents should be found:

```
{
  inv: [{ name: "Some Item", amount: 5 }]
}
//and
{
  inv: [{ name: "Another Item", amount: 15 }]
}
//and
{
  inv: [{ name: "Some Item", amount: 5 }, { name: "Another Item", amount: 15 }]
}
//and
{
inv: [{ name: "Some Item", amount: 5 }, { name: "Another Item", amount: 15 }, { name: "Different Item", amount: 1 }]
}
```

But these shouldn't:

```
{
  inv: [{ name: "Different Item", amount: 1 }]
}
//and
{
  inv: []
}
```

This works fine with regular MongoDB queries, but with Mongoose, this is a problem since you can't have multiple of the same properties in a JavaScript object (`name` and `name` in this case). How should I go about handling this?

Comment: May be you are looking for `$or` query operator. `db.collection.find({
  inv: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "$or": [
        {
          name: "Some Item"
        },
        {
          name: "Another Item"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yup, this works, thank you! Please turn this into an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator

```
db.collection.find({ inv: { $elemMatch: { "$or": [ { name: "Some Item" }, { name: "Another Item" } ] } } })
```